# Are event and event handling inherent part of JavaScript, the language itself?

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dom-events

Event and event handling are used in DOM, which is part of the standard library of JavaScript on the client side.

Are event and event handling inherent part of JavaScript, the language itself?

By the way, the description of tag [javascript-events] seems to say no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The DOM events you're referring to are described in the DOM specification only:

https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-event

Same thing for EventTarget:

> EventTarget is a DOM interface implemented by objects that can receive events and may have listeners for them.
>
> Element, Document, and Window are the most common event targets, but other objects can be event targets too, for example XMLHttpRequest, AudioNode, AudioContext, and others.
>
> Many event targets (including elements, documents, and windows) also support setting event handlers via onevent properties and attributes.

Events are not referred to anywhere in the [ECMAScript Language Specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/).

Of course, other interfaces (like for non-browsers) can have their own event-related objects as well.

Comment: Not really, nodejs also has a concept of Events, other APIs also have notions of Events that are not specifically based on the DOM ones. (See all the worklets for instance)

Answer (score 1):

No. [Here are the specs](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/), no Event there.